# EF6 Oracle packaged procedures not showing in entity model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, odp.net, oracle12c

I am relatively new to developing with EntityFramework. So pardon my ignorance if I am overlooking something.

Version Info: 
Visual Studio 2013
Oracle 12c: 12.1.0.2.0
Entity Framework Version: 6.1.1
ODP Managed Driver: 12.1.021

I am trying to import my datamodel into the project and on first look everything seemed fine. However, none of my packages were imported into the model.

I tried updating the model from database by importing a new procedure from the database (that I created as a simple procedure, not in a package) and it imported just fine. Is there something I am missing about importing packages?

Thanks much for any input you guys can provide.

Comment: do your procedures in packages return a sys_refcursor?

Comment: Is the package inside a pluggable database? If so, there was a bug similar to this and you should upgrade the database to a newer version (or reinstall without choosing "container database:").

Comment: Also, is this a ASP.NET project? You might try this on a new console project if so and see if you get different results, as there are some issues with ASP.NET project types.

Comment: @kevinsky - No my procedure does not return a sys_refcursor; just a varchar now. I should probably test sys_recursor as well.

Comment: @ChristianShay - Yes, this is inside a pluggable database and I think I saw something on the bug you refer to. I will try and see if I can get our team to upgrade our dev server. Thanks! 

PS. I will give the console application a shot as well. Thanks!